# Another CCS form alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a form with a descriptive label for an input box that wraps to a second line in the form window.  This is fine on it's own, but the input box ends up getting all screwed up since it seems to align to the top of the label rather than the bottom.  The question is, how do I get the input box to align to the bottom of the label?

Here is the CSS for the elements involved.

```css
label {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#defaultform input{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b9bdc1;
    width: 300px;
    color: #797979;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

Here is the HTML for the form:

```
<form id="defaultform" class="rounded" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1">
<h3>Show Hostess: <?php echo $row_HostessName['hostess_fname'] . " " . $row_HostessName['hostess_lname']; ?></h3>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="initial_date">Initial Date:</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="initial_date" value="" />
        <p class="hint">Enter initial show date.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="initial_time">Initial Time:</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="initial_time" value="" />
        <p class="hint">Enter initial show time.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="actual_datetime">Actual/Scheduled Date and Time:</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="actual_datetime" value="" />
        <p class="hint">Enter actual show date and time.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="number_of_guests">Number of Guests:</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="number_of_guests" value="" />
        <p class="hint">Enter number of guests at show.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="show_notes">Show Notes:</label>
        <input class="input" type="textarea" name="show_notes" value="" />
        <p class="hint">Enter number of guests at show.</p>
    </div>

    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add Show" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
```

`

The "Actual/Scheduled Date and Time" is the label that wraps and is causing me grief.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jts4q/1/) is a Fiddle of exactly what I'm seeing.

Comment: Could you provide the html for the form? http://cssdeck.com/labs/zt8tddog

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float property from the label tags:

CSS:

```
label {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
    display: block;
    /*float: left;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWfLc/)**

EDIT:

The easiest way to make the labels display to the left of the input boxes is to remove `display:block` from the label selector and put `<br />` tags after each input box: **[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWfLc/1/)**

Comment: That doesn't work for me as it drops the input box down below the label and I want it to be to the right of the label.

Comment: Still no go.  I increased the length of the label and it doesn't wrap, it then just drops the input box down below the label.  I am trying to get the label to wrap within it's confines, and the input box to align to the lowest line of this wrapping text.  I updated the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rWfLc/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using `Flex` layout. You can build a layout easily with that.

Is it what you mean?

Css :

```
label {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc; 
    font-weight: bold; margin-right:10px;
    width: 150px; line-height: 25px; font-size: 15px;
    text-align:right;
}

#defaultform input{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #b9bdc1; width: 300px; color: #797979;
    line-height: 16px;
}
.field{
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    align-items:center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    -o-align-items: center;
}
```

Html :

```
<form id="defaultform" class="rounded" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1">
    <h3>Show Hostess: <?php echo $row_HostessName['hostess_fname'] . " " . $row_HostessName['hostess_lname']; ?></h3>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="initial_date">Initial Date:</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="initial_date" value="" />   
    </div>
    <p class="hint">Enter initial show date.</p>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="actual_datetime">Actual/Scheduled Date and Time:</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="actual_datetime" value="" />
    </div>
    <p class="hint">Enter actual show date and time.</p>
</form>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jts4q/) is JsFiddle

Comment: Here is exactly what I'm seeing on my dev page with this code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jts4q/1/).  Specifically, the way the Actual/Scheduled label is wrapping and the input box for it being aligned at the top of the text and even more importantly what it does to the "Number of guests" label and it's input box.